# Changing graph to logarithmic scale and adding a 2nd Y-Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

Since the values for the "FPGA" (Brown) chart is really small(0.0002, green doesnt show up), i wanted to use logarithmic scale instead. I tried using  "ymode=log," but it makes the chart go wonky.

Additi[image]onally, I want to also add another right hand, y-axis to compare the throughput data, each bar graph having a value ranging from 0-2, probably a disconnected line plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Execution Time (ms)},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box,Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,33) (Gaussian,54)  (Box,127) (Sobel,246)  };%CPU
\addplot [fill=teal!]  coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,8.221) (Gaussian,13.3254)  (Box,14.958) (Sobel,29.935)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  (Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) };%FPGA
\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Algorithms Excluding Image Read/Write}
\label{imageexclude}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer because the result is not pretty. Rather this is to tell you that `ymode=log` does work, at least in principle. The reason why the results look "wonky" is that by default `log origin` is set to 1, so some of the bars hang in the air. Changing this and putting repeating keys in a style (I actually do not know why `ymode=log` cannot be part of the style but this only one key) yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{Freon axis/.style={ybar,
    ymin=0.00001,ymax=10000,%<- added ymax
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
                legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                },  
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic x coords={RGB2GRAY,Gaussian,Box, Sobel},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=east,rotate=-90,inner xsep=1pt},
    log origin=infty
}}
\begin{axis}[Freon axis,ymode=log,ylabel={Execution Time (ms)}]
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,54) (Gaussian,86)  (Box,154) (Sobel,268)  };%CPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,170.71) (Gaussian, 172.065)  (Box,193.72) (Sobel,215.38)  };%GPU
\addplot coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,20.234959834) (Gaussian,26.492609995)  (Box,27.353843832) (Sobel,45.59262995) };%FPGA
\legend{CPU,GPU,FPGA}
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[Freon axis,ymode=log,axis y line=right,ytick=\empty,
    ylabel={Throughput}]
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,21) (Gaussian,32)  (Box,27) (Sobel,40)  };%CPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,162.49) (Gaussian, 158.74)  (Box,178.76) (Sobel,169.79)  };%GPU
\addplot [fill=green] coordinates {(RGB2GRAY,0.0002) (Gaussian,0.0002)  (Box,0.0002) (Sobel,0.0002) };%FPGA
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Algorithms Including Image Read/Write.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is logarithmic but not pretty since now the brown bars grew but the red ones became too tiny. One could install a user transformation but I am not sure if this will then provide the viewer with the information you want to communicate.

Comment: I followed up on your question in the last  post i made, to do with accounts, seems like its not really visually appealing in that way. i may aswell put it as a note at the bottom.

Comment: @Freon Thanks! I Wass assuming this is the case.

Comment: Also to through on the question, how would i go around adding a 2nd y-axis on the right?, I had some extra numbers "Throughput" (for each hardward/algo) i generated. I presume a line plot would work.

Comment: @Freon I didn't understand that part. What do you mean by `another right hand, y-axis`? Is this a separate plot or on top of the others?

Comment: ill update the post with a visual image.

Comment: Added the image, and updated the latex i wanted to add the 2nd y-axis with. The throughput numbers just range from 0 - 2 (e.g. 1.261). In an overall sense, would a line graph be good here for additional comparison?

Comment: @Freon I added an ylabel on the right but the other statements I do not really understand. Where do you get these numbers from? Note that you generate your plot with explicit coordinates rather than from a table, so it will be hard to get an automatic solution that computes new values from the existing ones.

Comment: So i have two sets of data, the first being the execution time for each algorithm shown in the above graph.

The second set of data (Which is the throughput) i calculated for each algorithm/hardware. I have a new table of numbers now for each algorithm/hardware so the idea was to create a new y axis called throughput and add another plot to the graph to show both execution time and throughput. Yes! i will use explicit coordinates, i could add the throughput values up but you can just make up your own for example purposes. Also id like to thank you for taking your time out for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107846/discussion-between-freon-and-schrodingers-cat).